# Why I can't access the array element using it's key?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a bellow php `while` and `for` loop.

In `while` loop it's storing `$ch_for` data in `$ch_for` array.

Using `print_r` this array is showing these value :

```
Array ( [ch7] => Seven [ch8] => Eight )
```

And trying to access this `array` data in `for` loop using this line :

```
echo $ch_for["ch{$x}"];
```

But it's showing an error message : **Illegal string offset 'ch7' in**
 ...

**While and For Loop**

```
$ch_for     = array();
$ch_name    = array();

while ( $fetchChannel =  mysqli_fetch_array($getChannel) ) {
    $ch_id      = (int) $fetchChannel['ch_id'];
    $ch_for[$fetchChannel['ch_name']]   = htmlspecialchars($fetchChannel['ch_for']);
    $ch_name[]  = htmlspecialchars($fetchChannel['ch_name']);
}


for ($x=1; $x<=12; $x++) {
    if(  in_array('ch'.$x, $ch_name)) {
        $sel = 'checked = "checked" ';
        echo $ch_for["ch{$x}"];
    } else {
        $sel = '';
        $ch_for = '';
    }
    ?>

    <div class="checkbox form-inline">
        <label><input <?php echo $sel; ?> type="checkbox" name="ch_name[]" value="ch<?php echo $x; ?>">CH<?php echo $x; ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="ch_for[]" value="<?php echo $ch_for; ?>" placeholder="Channel details" class="form-control ch_for">
    </div>                                    
    <?php
}
```

Result of `var_dump(array_keys($ch_for));`

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "ch7"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "ch8"
}
```

Comment: Can you `var_dump(array_keys($ch_for));` and post the result? You're overwriting `$ch_for` in your else branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting `$ch_for` in your else-branch since the first key is `ch7`, hence the first loop (`ch1` is not in `$ch_name` and thus triggers the else) overwrites `$ch_for`.

Comment: Ah Sorry I don't get you. Can you show me please what I need to write ?

Comment: Your `$ch_for = '';` overwrites your complete array during the first iteration of your loop.

Comment: Oh I have fixed it. I got it, Thanks @ccKep :)

Answer (score 1):

Your array is associative array.SO use `in_array()` in `array_keys`.Like this..

```
   <?php
$array = array('ch7'=>'Seven','ch8'=>'Eight');

$keys = array_keys($array);

//print_r($keys);

for ($x=1; $x<=12; $x++) {
    if(  in_array('ch'.$x,$keys)) {
        $sel = 'checked = "checked" ';
        echo $array["ch{$x}"].PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        $sel = '';
        $ch_for = '';
    }
}    

?>
```

Output:

```
Seven
Eight
```